# How to change checkbox checked value in Knockout.js?

Tags: events, checkbox, knockout.js, binding, checked

I want to change checkbox value by jQuery, but Knockout bindings not working

```
var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable(true)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$(':checkbox').prop({checked: false}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stereodenis/n7zxvu01/3/

Comment: Don't use jquery directly if you working with Kncokout! just write `viewModel.myValue(false)`

Comment: /\  Agree with the above... do what he said instead of using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is described in the Knockout.js documentation: [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

```
<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {
    wantsSpam: ko.observable(true) // Initially checked
};

// ... then later ...
viewModel.wantsSpam(false); // The checkbox becomes unchecked
</script>
```